# Converting XML element into string and again string to XML file in python

Tags: python, xml, linux, web2py

How would I convert an XML element into string and a string back to XML format using xml.elementtree in web2py ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard library, you'd use the [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) writer and the [parseString](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.parseString) function:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
>>> e = parseString('<foo/>')
>>> out = StringIO()
>>> e.writexml(out)
>>> s = out.getvalue()
>>> print(s)
<?xml version="1.0" ?><foo/>
>>> e2 = parseString(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseString` to get xml element from string and `toxml` to make string out of xml element. Something like this.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

dom = minidom.parseString(content)
...
# do some changes to dom here
return dom.toxml()
```